# Navbar toggler not showing the list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently when the screen is minimized, the toggle button appears, but I would like to be able to click it and see the contents of the navbar when the screen is small. Currently clicking it doesn't do anything.
I googled it and came across a solution that many gave. They said to load the jQuery before the bootstrap JS file.I'm already doing that and it still doesn't do anything.
Can you guys help me out. I'm using bootstrap version 4.4.1.
I'm pasting my HTML code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name ="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <title>Assignment solution for module 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>
<body>

        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FOOD ,LLC</a>
                  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menuoption" aria-controls="         navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                     <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                  </button>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menuoption" >
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Chicken</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Beef</a>
                      </li>
                      <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Sushi</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
<script src="js/jsquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script src="js/jsquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>` is this loading the jquery? filename is jsquery-3.5.0.min.js or jquery-3.5.0.min.js?

Comment: @Haque Yes. I've kept it in the js folder.

Comment: filename is **jsquery-3.5.0.min.js** or **jquery-3.5.0.min.js** ?

Comment: @Haque My bad. It was actually jquery .I changed it but still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: try with jquery version 3.3.1 `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js`

Comment: @Haque YES!! It worked. Thankyou so much. You saved my ass man.
Anyways do you know why this error happened with jQuery 3.5.0?

Comment: Bootstrap having some compatibility issues with jquery-3.5.0 , that's all i can say for now

Answer (score 0):

Try to use lower version of jquery (ie: jquery v3.3.1) for now. bootstrap is not compatible with v3.5.0 yet.